# Proving that $2^{2n}-n^2+3^n = \Omega (2^{2n})$

Tags: asymptotics

I need to prove that: $2^{2n}-n^2+3^n = \Omega (2^{2n})$
I started and got to this: $2^{2n}-n^2+3^n \geq 2^{2n}\cdot 3 \geq 2^{2n}\cdot 2 = 2^{2n+1}$ for every $n > n_{0} = 1$ 
How should I continue from here?

Comment: If $n=4$, $2^{2\cdot4}-4^2+3^4 = 321$ and $2^{2\cdot4}\cdot 3=768$, so the first part of your inequality ($2^{2n}-n^2+3^n \geq 2^{2n}\cdot 3$) is not correct.

Comment: $2^{2n} - n^2 + 3^n > 2^{2n}$ for non-negative $n$

Answer (score 0):

Assume $n \in \mathbb{R}$ and $n > 0$.

$$2^{2n} - n^2 + 3^n > 2^{2n}$$
$$3^n > n^2$$

This should be relatively easy to show right?

Comment: Hmm how do I show that?